# How to run regression instead of classification in random forest in R?

Tags: regression, random-forest

I run this code in R

```
model_bf_df <- randomForest(Amountspent.x ~ ., data = train_bf_df, ntree = 130, mtry=59, importance = TRUE, do.trace=TRUE)
```

Amountspent.x is a continues variable and taken values from train data set which I split earlier from the main dataset. I have been getting classification type instead of regression. What changes should I make? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The randomForest package automatically determines the type of problem based on the class of y, Amountspent.x in your case. Your DV must be a factor or something other than numeric. Make sure you properly converted it into numeric format. Check with `class(train_bf_df$Amountspent.x)`.